# $R\cong \prod_{i=1}^{n}R/B_{i}$ where $B_{i}=\sum_{j\neq i}^{n}A_{j}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Can anyone give me a suggestion to solve this problem?

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity. Suppose $R$ is the direct sum of ideals $A_{1},\ldots,A_{n}$. Prove the following.

a) $R\cong \prod_{i=1}^{n}R/B_{i}$ where $B_{i}=\sum_{j\neq i}^{n}A_{j}$

b) Each $A_{i}$ is a commutative ring with unit isomorphic a $R/B_{i}$

c) The identity element $e_{i}$ of $A_{i}$ is idempotent on $A$ and $A_{i} = (e_{i})$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First notice that solving b) will most likely suffice in solving a), because if everything goes nice, $A_i\simeq R/B_i$, and so $R=\displaystyle\sum A_i \simeq \prod A_i \simeq \prod R/B_i$.

Next notice also that b) will help solving c), in that if $A_i$ is a commutative ring with unit, call $1_i$ the unit of $A_i$. Then $1_i \times 1_i =  1_i^2$ but also $1_i\times 1_i = 1_i$ since $1_i$ is a unit in $A_i$. Therefore $1_i = 1_i^2$. Furthermore, $(1_i)\subset A_i$, and if $k\in A_i$, then $k= k1_i$ since $1_i$ is a unit, and thus $k\in (1_i)$: $A_i = (1_i)$. Therefore if we solve b), we don't even have to look further for b).

Now let $\pi$ be the canonical projection $R\to R/B_i$. We then look at $\pi_i$, the restriction of $\pi$ to $A_i$. What we want to show is that $\pi_i$ is an isomorphism.

First, it's injective. Indeed, assume $\pi_i(x) =0$. Then $\pi(x)=0$. Thus by definition, $x\in \displaystyle\sum_{j\neq i} A_j$. But also $x\in A_i$. Sine the sum of the $A_i$'s is direct this implies $x=0$. Hence, $\pi_i$ is injective.

Then, it's surjective. Indeed let $x\in R$. We need to show that there exists $y\in A_i$, such that $x=y$ (mod $B_i$). 
For this we write $x=\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^n x_j$, with $x_j\in A_j$ (possible by assumption). But then, $x= x_i$ (mod $B_i$), and $x_i\in A_i$. Thus it's surjective.

Therefore $\pi_i : A_i \simeq R/B_i$. Since $R$ is a commutative ring with a unit, so is $R/B_i$, and since they're isomorphic, so is $A_i$.

So we've solved b). From this we get a) and c), as noticed above.